# How can I get fields from a selected table from a SQL Server 2014 database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my code:

```
namespace Modulul_3_proiect
{
    public partial class FormSimpleWizard : Form
    {
        public FormSimpleWizard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            incarcaComboBoxSimpleWiz(comboBoxWS);
        }

        //method to extract tables from BD
        public IList<string> ListTables()
         {
            DBConnection db = DBConnection.getConexiune;
            SqlConnection conexiune = db.conn;

            List<string> tables = new List<string>();
            DataTable dt = conexiune.GetSchema("Tables");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string tablename = (string)row[2];
                tables.Add(tablename);
            }
            return tables;
        }
        //method to load combobox with tables
        private void incarcaComboBoxSimpleWiz(ComboBox cb)
        {
            IList<string> tabeleWizard=ListTables();
            cb.Items.Clear();
            cb.Items.Add("Select tables");
            foreach (String tip in tabeleWizard)
                cb.Items.Add(tip);
            cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

After I loaded the combobox with the tables from my SQL Server database, I want to get the fields of the selected table in the combobox and show them in a textbox multiline so I can make a query after.

Comment: Any concrete problem with doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] getColumnsName(string tname)
{
    List<string> listacolumnas=new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = tname and t.type = 'U'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listacolumnas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
    return listacolumnas.ToArray();
}
```

are you sure you are passing in the correct table name?

try this

select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = 'your table name' and t.type = 'U'

on t-sql

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but when I try to load them into the text box an exception is thrown "object reference not set to an instance of an object". It seems that the value returned by this function is null. And I don't really understand the code from the command. Could you explain a little? I am just starting to use C# so I'm not very skilled..

Comment: select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = 'your table name' and t.type = 'U'

Comment: try the above sql statement with 'your table name'